# VB.NET Make a Date out of just Day

Tags: vb.net, date, days

My user will typically enter some trip info including a day and month but typically they just enter the day. For example they would enter `"TRIP1500/31"` where the 31 is implied that its in JULY. The trip date can be at most 7 days in the past or 7 days in the future. So now what Im trying to do is guess what month that day is meant to be. So far I have:

```
Dim diff As Integer = CInt(tripDay) - Date.Now.Day
Select Case diff
    Case 0
        'same day so its probably current month
End Select
```

What I'm having trouble with is the other cases where the current day and the trip day overlap month-to-month. If the current day and trip day are in current month then the most difference they can be is +/-7 days but what about the other cases? Any help appreciated.

Comment: So +/- 7 days is the maximum difference?

Comment: I do not fully understand what you are asking. Are you asking how to find current date and add or subtract 7 days from it?

Comment: What if a user enters a day that is not +/-7 days from today? Are you doing validation to prevent that before this Case statement or are you planning on using this Case statement you have going to incorporate that?

Comment: Im asking how to guess at what month a day is. in this case the 31. but it can be any day just within 7 days of the current computer date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function GetTripDate(day As Integer) As Date

    Dim today As Date = Date.Today

    For i As Integer = -7 To 7
        Dim dt As Date = today.AddDays(i)
        If dt.Day = day Then Return dt
    Next

    Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid trip day.")

End Function
```

Comment: This one is an interesting approach. Let me digest the logic.

Comment: I think I like this approach for its simplicity and i can also tweak the range values. many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the date(incl. month) of the nearest date with the given day:

```
Dim maxDiffDays = 7
Dim tripDay = 31
Dim today = Date.Today
Dim tripDate = New Date(today.Year, today.Month, tripDay)
Dim tripDates = {tripDate.AddMonths(-1), tripDate, tripDate.AddMonths(1)}
Array.Sort(Of Date)(tripDates, Function(d1, d2) ((today - d1).Duration).CompareTo((today - d2).Duration))
Dim nearestDate = tripDates.First()
If ((today - nearestDate).Days <= maxDiffDays) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Nearest month for trip date is: " & nearestDate.Month)
End If
```

It creates a `Date` from a given day, then it creates the two surrounding dates one month after and previous this date. This array will be sorted from the positive timespan from today(`TimeSpan.Duration`). So the firs't date in the array is the nearest date with the correct month.

Comment: Let me give this one a go and do some testing. will get back with results